# Detect sliding up gesture on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, uigesturerecognizer

Which gesture am I looking to capture if I want to detect when the user slides his/her finger upwards (think of scrubbing through a song, that kind of motion, but up) and adjust a setting as a result (I don't want to use a UISlider).

What would you guys recommend for this? Is that a pan gesture recognizer or a swipe?

Comment: I guess pan gesture would work out for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = 
[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
 initWithTarget:self 
 action:@selector(swipeDetected)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

A swipe is one-time simple motion; observe that it happened, and you respond *afterwards*. A pan gesture is a continuous movement that you want to able to track while it happens. Which of those do you want?

Comment: A pan, by your description. Is it possible to make sure the pan only goes up, however?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to write a subclass. I have code showing how to write a pan gesture recognizer that only recognizes vertical motion; you could adapt that so that it only recognizes vertical motion *upwards* if you want. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_subclassing_gesture_recognizers